# JavaScript create image from blob results in broken image

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob

I get a buffer from the server and create a new blob. For this new blob I create an Object URL, but the image is always displayed incorrectly.

This is the buffer im getting from the server:
[Buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPF3b.png)

This is how i am creating the object url for the blob:
[Creating object url from blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txa0v.png)

And the result is this:
[Final image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfg68.png)

Also there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please put relevant code as text in the question not as images. See [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Also provide enough data to create a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates the issue and allows us to test the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your byte array to an Uint8Array and see if it works

```
var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(artifactEntityObject.thumbnail.data);
var blob = new Blob( [arrayBufferView], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
var imgSource = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
```

Comment: This works without problems, thank you very much! Could you please explain what the difference is between the buffer itself and the UInt8 array, both look the same to me in the dev tool

Comment: Actually I'm not 100% sure. My guess is, and as per the documentation, the Blob constructor expects an ArrayBuffer or a Typed Array and doesn't know how to handle a array of javascript integers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob

Comment: Ahhh i understand, anyway, thank you very much for the solution!